# passing JS array to controller's action

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

```
 <form action="" onsubmit="getSelectedPlace(this);" target="_blank">
        <div class="wrap_input">
            <input type="submit" id="myDiv" class="btn buy_btn" value="Done">
        </div>
        </form>

 function getSelectedPlace(form) {
        var placesID = new Array();
        $(".place.green").each(function () {
            placesID.push($(this).attr("id"));
        });

        form.action = "/Pay/Buy?places=" + placesID;
        return true;
    }
```

In the `getSelectedPlace` I get `ID` and push it in the array, and fill `action`.
My action:

```
 public ActionResult Buy(string[] places)
            {
                return new EmptyResult();
            }
```

In the firebug `placesID` is filled. But in my action  `places` is `null`. If I change `string[]` to simple `string` then result is the same.
Where is a problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:
Add `HttpPost` to action and add `method="POST"` to the form.

Answer (score 2):

Please notice traditional parameter serialization. More details here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var strArray = new Array();

    strArray[0] = "P1";
    strArray[1] = "P2";

    var params = { data: strArray };

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/Test",
        data: params,
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true
    });
</script>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Test(string[] data)
{
    @ViewBag.Test = data[0]; // Data will be set to P1
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `string` only. separate it by comma or any other notation you want.

```
function getSelectedPlace(form) {
    var placesID = "";
    $(".place.green").each(function () {
        placesID = $(this).attr("id") +  "," + placesID;
    });

    form.action = "/Pay/Buy?places=" + placesID;
    return true;
}
```

In action,

```
public ActionResult Buy(string places)
        {
            string[] placesArray = places.Split(",");
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

Also using `onsubmit="getSelectedPlace(this);"` is not safe. use `onsubmit="return getSelectedPlace(this);"`